# How to combine an aggregate sql query and a normal query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 that I want to aggregate data from, here is an example.

```
JobName       ProductionCounter       StartDate             EndDate               CounterName        Stage
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

200           23                      2012-08-30 13:45:00                          Kilograms          Final
200           2                       2012-08-30 13:45:00                          Bars               Final
    [...]
200           46                      2012-08-30 13:45:00   2012-08-30 17:23:00    Kilograms          Final
200           4                       2012-08-30 13:45:00   2012-08-30 17:23:00    Bars               Final
300           20                      2012-08-30 13:45:00                          Kilograms          1st
300           10                      2012-08-30 18:12:00                          Bars               1st
    [...]
300           40                      2012-08-30 18:12:00   2012-08-30 19:17:00    Kilograms          1st
300           20                      2012-08-30 18:12:00   2012-08-30 19:17:00    Bars               1st
```

I want to format this into the following

```
JobName      TotalKilos       TotalBars       StartDate             EndDate               Stage
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
200          69               6               2012-08-30 13:45:00   2012-08-30 17:23:00   Final
300          60               30              2012-08-30 18:12:00   2012-08-30 19:17:00   1st
```

This has made me realise I know nothing about SQL. I have tried the following as a start

```
SELECT JobName, SUM(ProductionCounter)
FROM vwOeeInterval
WHERE (CounterName = 'Kilos')
GROUP BY JobName

SELECT JobName, SUM(ProductionCounter)
FROM vwOeeInterval
WHERE (CounterName = 'Bars')
GROUP BY JobName
```

My questions are:

1. How do I combine these into one query?
2. How would I query for the columns such as `StartDate` and `Stage`? Especially where the `EndDate` is not filled in until the job completes?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to group by the data first and then apply the pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT 
JobName, 
SUM(CASE CounterName WHEN 'Kilos' THEN ProductionCounter ELSE 0 END) AS SumKilos,
SUM(CASE CounterName WHEN 'Bars' THEN ProductionCounter ELSE 0 END) AS SumBars,
MIN(StartDate), 
MAX(COALESCE(EndDate, 'undefined date')), 
MAX(Stage)
FROM vwOeeInterval
WHERE CounterName IN ('Kilos', 'Bars')
GROUP BY JobName;
```

Not sure if this `MAX(COALESCE(EndDate, 'undefined date'))` works in SQL Server, since datatype's might clash. You just need COALESCE(), when you want to replace the NULL value. If it does not work, just do MAX(EndDate) and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them

```
SELECT 
    JobName, CounterName, SUM(ProductionCounter),
    MIN(StartDate), MAX(EndDate), MAX(Stage)
FROM vwOeeInterval  
GROUP BY JobName , CounterName
```

and filter them with

```
HAVING MAX(EndDate) > SomeDate OR MAX(EndDate) is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe that is what you need:

```
   SELECT JobName, SUM(TotalKilos),  SUM(ProductionCounter), MAX(StartDate) , MAX(EndDate), MAX(Stage)
    GROUP BY JobName , CounterName, StartDate, EndDate
    --Optional:
    WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL
```

NOTE: Stage is only working in alphabetical order, may if you have a bigger starter letter then 'F' it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To combine your queries:

```
SELECT JobName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CounterName = 'Kilos' THEN ProductionCounter ELSE 0 END) AS TotalKilos,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CounterName = 'Bars' THEN ProductionCounter ELSE 0 END) AS TotalBars
    FROM vwOeeInterval
    GROUP BY JobName;
```

Then, to wrap up the rest, perhaps:

```
SELECT JobName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CounterName = 'Kilos' THEN ProductionCounter ELSE 0 END) AS TotalKilos,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CounterName = 'Bars' THEN ProductionCounter ELSE 0 END) AS TotalBars,
       MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
       MAX(Stage) AS Stage
    FROM vwOeeInterval
    GROUP BY JobName;
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Answer (score 0):

```
select jobname, max(bars) as "TotalBars", max(kg) as "Total Kilos", sd as "Start date", ed as "End date" from(
SELECT JobName, if(countername="bars",SUM(ProductionCounter),null) as "bars" , if(countername="kilograms",SUM(ProductionCounter),null) as "kg" , min(startdate) as sd, max(enddate) as ed
FROM vwOeeInterval
GROUP BY JobName , CounterName) t
group by jobname
```